# How to get this value using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

This is the snippet from the page:

```
<br><b>Price:</b>&nbsp;Rs. 24,900.00&nbsp;<br>
```

I need to get the value `Rs.24,900.00`. But I'm not sure how to get it, since it is not enclosed by any element.

I used this: `doc.select("b:contains(Price:)");` to get to the `Price:` element.

But how would I get that `Rs.24,900.00` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse( "<br><b>Price:</b> &nbsp; Rs. 24,900.00 &nbsp; <br>");

Element el = doc.select("b").first(); //get the element which contains "Price:"

String text = ((TextNode) el.nextSibling()).text();
```

Here, first I have to obtain the element which contains `Price:`.
Then we can get it's nextsibling and use `text()` method to get its text.

Thanks to [user1121883](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121883/user1121883) for his answer on similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251045/how-to-get-text-which-is-not-part-of-any-element-using-jsoup).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control over the source of the HTML? If so you should never create content with free text. It should always reside in an element, even if it is just a p tag. (The body element does not count. Body should not contain text.)

Otherwise you are limited to text based searching.

Comment: No. I don't have control over that HTML. How could I get that value? I can't use text base searching because that number changes for every url I need to parse.

Comment: Find <b>Price:</b>. Then using that as a starting point look for the &nbsp; entities. If they always surround the value you are looking for then you can just use them as a starting and ending point of your search.

Comment: I'm sure that &nbsp always surrounds that value and I got to that <b>Price<b> element too as mentioned in question. But how do I go from there @markbernard ?

Comment: Jsoup can't help you here you have to use Java String class with indexOf("") and indexOf("", lastIndex). You may be able to use a Regex to get it as well.