# How to get text which is not part of any element using jsoup?

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

How to get the text which is not part of any element?

```
<br><b>Price:</b> &nbsp; Rs. 24,900.00 &nbsp; <br>
```

Here, how can one get the text `Rs.24,900.00`. Is this possible using jsoup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert xPath to JSoup query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335820/convert-xpath-to-jsoup-query)

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think that question is different as I'm not dealing with xpath at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there is a parent element so you should select that first and after just select the "b" like the following code. Basically just find the element in front of your text.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse( "<br><b>Price:</b> &nbsp; Rs. 24,900.00 &nbsp; <br>");
Element el = doc.select("b").first();
String text = ((TextNode) el.nextSibling()).text();
```

I used first because I knew from your example that there is only one "b" element. In case you have multiple prices you have to iterate over all elements instead of using first.

Jsoup stores text as nodes. So nextSibling will return a node (TextNode) that follows after the "b" element and contains text value: "  Rs. 24,900.00  "

Comment: Oops! I'm getting an error : TextNode cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: import org.jsoup.nodes.*;

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But why do we need first()? and  nextSibling means &nbsp right?

Comment: @nikhil will add explanations in answer